# Joining a table on an id but need to copy this data to other ids

Tags: postgresql, join, query

I have an issue with a postgres database that I am not sure how to handle.
These are the tables (simplified obviously)

Users

```
+--+---------+
|id|user info|
+--+---------+
|10|{data}   |
|11|{data}   |
+--+---------+
```

Devices

```
+--+------+----------+
|id|userid|other info|
+--+------+----------+
|1 |10    |{data}    |
|2 |10    |{data}    |
|3 |11    |{data}    |
+--+------+----------+
```

Device_Preference

```
+--+------+------------+
|id|userid|preferenceid|
+--+------+------------+
|1 |10    |8           |
|2 |10    |9           |
|3 |11    |8           |
+--+------+------------+
```

Preferences

```
+--+---------------+
|id|preference info|
+--+---------------+
|8 |{data}         |
|9 |{data}         |
+--+---------------+
```

Preferences are linked to user, not device so I am looking for a query that gives me the preferences for every device, like this:

```
+--------+------+----------+
|deviceid|userid|prefenceid|
+--------+------+----------+
|1       |10    |8         |
|1       |10    |9         |
|2       |10    |8         |
|2       |10    |9         |
|3       |11    |8         |
+--------+------+----------+
```

I think a 'select Devices d1 join Devices d2 on d1.userid=d2.userid' is needed but I am not sure exactly how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT d.id deviceid, u.id userid, dp.preferenceid
FROM Users u, Devices d, Device_Preference dp
WHERE u.id = dp.userid
  AND u.id = d.userid
ORDER BY 1,3
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b26c95fb570ff7feb94616b13a000242)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.